# jQuery / CSS iPhone - Click Event

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, mobile

I have a jQuery calendar running, and in order to see the day's events, the user must click a span cell. The issue is the span is surrounded with an href that uses a CSS class that has an empty.gif background:

```
.dayspan { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 1; background-image: url('empty.gif'); }   

<a href="events/day/"><span class="dayspan"></span></a>
```

It works perfectly on desktops and all browsers. The problem is mobile devices don't seem to like this and it sometimes requires upwards of 4 clicks to activate the link.

Any ideas on how else I could link to my content within the cell?
Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what is or isn't happening, so you may need to elucidate. What happens on desktops (that isn't happening on the iPhone) when the link is clicked?

Comment: On a desktop the span just opens the new link. When on a mobile phone, the entire span just "blinks" - it looks like it activates but it does nothing until several click attempts are made.

Comment: The strange thing is when I turn the phone to landscape, I click the span and it works perfectly with no screen "flicker".

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble testing it, try it on safari.  A few mobile issue's I've debugged were easier when I was able to simulate the bug in a browser.
If not try Chrome and adjust the browser version under settings to use an older version to try to get the error.
Anyway if you are just firing an event it might be easier to just use an onclick event that adds those css elements to the dom element, then you shouldn't have to worry about where the code is being ran.